# php - which one is better approach null== or ==null

Tags: php, syntax

I saw many times that php developers use somthing like this:

```
if(null == $var){

}
```

while I use

```
if($var == null){

}
```

Are these two different? is there any reason to use each one? or it is a choice matter in any ways?

Comment: `$var==null` is the standard way .. There is no difference in the two. its just standard we always write the valee in right

Comment: The advantage of the first one is that you get a syntax error in case of accidental typos like `(null = $var)` which would pass and create confusion otherwise.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I _strongly_ disagree.

Comment: @arkascha please mention reason so i can also know

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI consider yourself enlightened , arkashra has provided already.  Typos are not the only reason for this common error.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yes  wasn't considering that small point ..

Comment: It's exactly the same thing.

Comment: thanks for anyone who post a comment or answer, I got my answer. all answers and related comments seems true. I know some c language too so I thinkk its a good point. so I would select all answers, but I can select one answer and give a up vote to others. thanks anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply `null` can't be assigned value
`null = $a`, it will throw parsing error.

but any variable can have `null` as value.
`$a = null`

So if you mistyped `==` to `=` in the second case, you have changed the value of `$a` and you check the if condition of the new value of `$a` which always evaluates to false.

Comment: @bub I know, but that's the reason and it comes from C world and embedded systems where debugging is much harder..
So it's old used defensive technique to avoid mistyping comparison with assigning

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, it's exactly the same thing. Long answer:

The C programming language allows assignment within the condition. e.g.

`(i = 1)==1` is valid. This means that:

```
if (x = null)
```

is valid as well.

In some cases you intended to assign x = null but (most often) you just intended to compare `x == null` and mistyped.

Therefore developers in C (or C++) would do something like:

```
if (null == x)
```

This is because if it was mistyped to `if (null = x)` it would not compile.

However in PHP this is no longer a valid reason since PHP is not compiled therefore such errors are not trapped early and this defeats the whole purpose of the reversed syntax.

However, the advantage of using it in PHP is that when you do hit that part of the code, it will error instead of running normally and will therefore inform you of the problem.

On the other hand in PHP you should really use `===` so typos would lead to `==` anyway.